# How to accumulate the number of appearance of an integer sequence?

Tags: matlab, bsxfun, accumarray

I have a sequence of integers, say `arr = [1,5,2,2,5,1]`.

I need a structure, say `Counter`, that can tell me how many times the integer appears.

I have the following code but it won't work since `isfield` cannot be used in this way.

```
for i = 1 : length(arr)
  if ~isfield(Counter, i)
    Counter{i} = 0;
  end
  Counter{i} = Counter{i} + 1
end
```

So is there any elegant way that can accumulate the number of appearance of an integer sequence?

Answer (score 3):

```
A = [1 2 1 2 3 3 1 4 5 5 6];
numbers = unique(A); % [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] unique elements
count = histc(A, numbers); % [3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1] occurrence of the element
```

The two core commands are [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html).

Answer (score 2):

Two other possibilities, in addition to `histc`:

1. Use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to test for equality and then sum all coincidences for each number:

   ```
   A = [1 2 1 2 3 3 1 4 5 5 6];
   count = sum(bsxfun(@eq, A(:), min(A):max(A)));
   ```
2. Use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to sum `1` for each occurrence of each number:

   ```
   count = accumarray(A(:)-min(A)+1, 1, []).';
   ```

In both cases, `count(1)` is the number of ocurrences of `min(A)`, `count(2)` is the number of ocurrences of `min(A)+1`, ..., `count(end)` is the number of occurrences of `max(A)` (some of which may be zero).

Comment: My two favorite functions in one answer. However, if `min(A)>1`, then `count(1)` from `accumarray` will be zero instead of the count because it gets padded with zeros.  I think you'd need to do `count = accumarray(A(:), 1).'; count(1:min(A)-1)=[]` or something similar. And if `A` can be negative, then it could get ugly, having to use `unique` first.

Comment: @chappjc I knew you'd like this answer, having these two functions :-) (two of my favourite too). Thanks for your insightful comments. I have corrected by adding `-min(A)+1` to `A`